# Use a Mock PHPUnit in non-test class

Tags: mocking, phpunit, stub

For one project, I have to made a mock of a class, and I want to use this mock in my code to simulate a behaviour. 
In my Test class I put this code :

```
public function testExportCsv()
{
    $mockObject = $this->getMockBuilder('\Client')
        ->setConstructorArgs(array("0"))
        ->getMock();
    $res = $this->searchDocApiDocumentsStub();
    $mockObject->method('searchDocuments')
        ->willReturn($res);
}

public function searchDocApiDocumentsStub()
{
    $res = array();
    $yml = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents("../src/ExportCSVBundle/Resources/config/generic.yml"));
    $typeDoc = "FAC";
    $metas[$typeDoc] = $yml["ETT"][strtoupper($typeDoc)];


    foreach ($this->documents as $document) {
        if ($document["type"] == "DocumentsAPI\\Model\\" . str_replace('$eq ', '', $typeDoc)) {
            foreach ($metas[$typeDoc] as $field) {
                $docres[] = $document["metas"][$field];
            }
            $res = array_merge($res, $docres);
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

In an other class "Export" I have to use the class I mock, in attribute this class has an object of "Client", the class I Mock. 
Then i Have to use this object.

```
class Export {
    public function __construct(Client $docApiClient)
    {
        $this->docApiClient = $docApiClient;
    }

    $docs = $this->docApiClient->searchDocuments($client, $query, null, false, false, $metasToExport);
```

I want this "searchDocuments" to be the Stub I made.

```
$export = new \ExportLibraryBundle\ExportLibrary\Export(//What Do I put ??);
```

I don't know if I am clear but thank you for your help.

Comment: But my mockObject is in a test class, how do I inject it in my class "Export" ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that PHPUnit's default mock engine strongly depends on PHPUnit itselt.

If you want to use mocks outside PHPUnit tests you can use external mock library, ie. Mockery. It's very similar, except is doesn't depend on PHPUnit and has some great features PHPUnit Mocks doesn't have (ie. demeter chain mock).

See http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/

You can see some examples and comparisons here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mockery-a-better-way--net-28097

Comment: Thank you I will check that !